# What's the best way to store potatoes and maximize their shelf-life?

Tags: storage-method, potatoes

What's the best place and way to store potatoes so they keep fresh longest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best thing to do is to keep them out of the light in an cool dark dry place. I usually put them in a hessian bag to try and keep the moisture away.

Don't store them in the fridge or anywhere that gets direct sunlight.

Comment: Also don't buy potatoes that were washed. Unwashed potatoes are dirty, but they last longer and there's smaller chance that they will start to rot or get a mold. And you should always wash your potatoes before you use them anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Potatoes should be stored at [temperatures between 7 and 9 degrees](http://www.slhfarm.com/storing.html) C (45 to 50 degrees Fahrenheit). The starches in the potato will start to break down into sugars at temperatures below 7 degrees making for a darker, more bitter tasting result after frying or roasting.

Many people say that you shouldn't store potatoes in the fridge. If, like me, you have a compartment in your fridge that goes above 7 degrees, I believe it is reasonable to keep them there despite common misgivings.

Air circulation is important according to [one internet source](http://www.uwex.edu/energy/potato.html) to "remove the products of respiration". A cool, well ventilated cellar would be the ideal place to store them.

The first article I linked to seems to suggest that you can store potatoes at lower temperatures for a few months.

Answer (score 3):

I recently bought [this jar](http://www.chefscatalog.com/product/23810-fresh-valley-canisters.aspx) to hold potatoes. It has holes in the bottom to allow a little bit of circulation. So far I am very happy with it.